# Query on inverse relationship

Tags: relationship, realm

I am new to Realm and having problem with query that drive me crazy for several days. I have 2 simple classes Dog and Person as:

```
class Dog: Object {
    dynamic var dogName = ""
    dynamic var dogAge = 1
    var owners: [Person] {
       return linkingObjects(Person.self, forProperty: "dogs")
    }
}

class Person: Object {
    dynamic var firstName = ""
    let dogs = List<Dog>()
}
```

After adding data to Realm, I have the following data:

- Oscar have 3 dogs namely A, B and C with respected age of 4, 6, and 9
- Jennifer have 3 dogs namely D,E and F with respected age of 1, 2 and 7
- One dog named Z, age 8 and have no owner.

```
let database = try! Realm()
// Query all Dogs- It should have 7 dogs
let allDogs = database.objects(Dog)
print("A total of \(allDogs.count) dogs")   // 7 dogs - correct

// Query All dogs between age of 4 and 12 - there should be 5 dogs

let agedDogs = database.objects(Dog).filter("dogAge BETWEEN {4,12}")
print("Dogs between Age 4 and 12 = \(agedDogs.count) \n")   // 5 dogs - OK
```

I want to know of all those `agedDog`, how many of them belong to Oscar?
I tried:

```
let specificOwnerAgedDogs = agedDogs.filter("ANY owners.firstName = 'Oscar'")
print("Oscar Dogs between Age 4 and 12 = \(specificOwnerAgedDogs)")
```

But this query results in an error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Invalid property name', reason: 'Property 'owners' not found in object of type 'Dog''

I am using the Realm Swift with Swift 2.1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realm Swift [does not yet support provide direct support for queries that traverse inverse relationships](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1324), such as the `owners` property on your `Dog` class. This is something we're working on, and that should make it into a Realm Swift release in the near future.

For now, you can work around this limitation by performing some of the filtering in Swift rather than in the predicate:

```
let specificOwners = database.objects(Person).filter("firstName = 'Oscar'")
let specificOwnerAgedDogs = specificOwners.flatMap() { owner in
    owner.dogs.filter() { $0.dogAge >= 4 && $0.dogAge <= 12 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I feel better now. Thanks for the solution as well

Comment: However, my final goal is to find all the dogs from age 4 to 12 that do not have an owner so somebody can adopt his/her

Comment: The feature request, linked above, tracking this functionality has been closed for a couple of years.

Answer (score 0):

```
let noOwn = agedDogs.flatMap {
   (ndog) -> Dog? in
   ndog.owners == [] ? ndog : nil
}
```

I use this code to find out the list of all agedDogs that do not any owner?
Any thought on this?